# What are the best and worst case scenarios of an algorithm that partitions around the maximum value in an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pivot, partitioning, partition

I have been given this algorithm that takes the maximum item (let’s call it m) in an array A and partitions around it such that all the items smaller than m go in a set A1 and all those bigger or equal go in A2. Eventually, it goes recursively on A1 and uses InsertionSort on A2. It terminates after concatenating A1 and A2 in A.

First of all I don’t really get why it uses insertionSort on A2 (I mean, m is the maximum, so A2 will only contain elements that are equal to the maximum). Anyway, one of the questions is about finding worst and best case scenarios and their time complexity. As for the worst case time complexity I think it’s O(n^2), but I’m not quite sure (It should be like SelectionSort, right?) As for the rest I don’t really know..